# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on line in TableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to set the value of a label in my table view cell (itemDescrip to @"body"), and for some reason this line is throwing me a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error:

```
NSDictionary *node = [self.descripData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

I'm not sure why. The data populating the label is coming from a Drupal endpoint (successfully, when I log my array, descripData). So I'm not sure why the line is giving me grief. Thoughts?

**ViewController.h**

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSArray *descripData;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableDictionary *viewParams = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [viewParams setValue:@"storeditems" forKey:@"view_name"];
    [DIOSView viewGet:viewParams success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        self.descripData = responseObject;
        NSLog(@"%@",self.descripData);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *DoctorsTableIdentifier = @"StorageItemTableViewCell";

    StorageItemTableViewCell *cell = (StorageItemTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DoctorsTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StorageItemTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        NSDictionary *tmp = [self.storageData objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(long)indexPath.row]];

        [[cell itemName] setText:(NSString *)[tmp objectForKey:@"title"]];

        NSString *title = [tmp objectForKey:@"title"];
        [[cell itemName] setText:title];

        NSDictionary *node = [self.descripData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [[cell itemDescrip] setText:[node objectForKey:@"body"]];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the crash stack trace. However, it's most likely due to a nil value. Put in some NSLogs (in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`) or breakpoints to see if your values exist.

Comment: Any particular reason why you declare your `descripData` with the `assign` attribute? That's generally not done for object types in like 99.99% of cases. Maybe try removing the `assign` attribute to make the property strong and see what happens.

Comment: If you get this while running it from Xcode, there should also be a message in the debug console describing the exception.  What do you see there?

Comment: Hey @DrBeardface, you're a genius. Removed assign and replaced it with strong; magical. Thank you!! :)